# Replace trailing {

Tags: regex, vim

I have a text

```
int strlindex(char s[], char t[]) {
```

that I would like to change into

```
int strlindex(char s[], char t[]);
```

using `Vim`. I've tried

`%s/\{$/;/g`

but to no avail. Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe you can find something over here? http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Search_and_replace

Answer (score 3, accepted):

what I see from the codes in your question is, you want to do this:

```
:%s/\s*{\s*$/;/
```

**some notes**

- you **should not** escape the `{` unless you use `very magic` (`\v`)
- you have one space before the `{`, and apparently you want it to be removed in result. so we need `\s*` before `{`
- There might be spaces too between `{` and `$`. so I add another `\s*`
- you don't need the `g` flag, one line has only one `$`
- also you had a `%` before the `s/../../` it will do this replacement on whole file. If there are normal functions with this structure, the `{` would be removed. **Do a double check after the substitution, to make sure it didn't destroy your codes.**

Answer (score 3):

perhaps you have some whitespace after the `{`

`%s/{\s*$/;/g`

Answer (score 2):

Usually in Vim regular expressions `{` is a literal brace and doesn't need to be escaped. This is true for `magic` and `non-magic` regular expressions (the exception is if you specify the `very-magic` option - see `help: magic` for more information.

So this will work:

```
%s/{$/;/g
```

Answer (score 1):

The escaping isn't necessary here, `%s/{$/;/g` works fine.